# Zend Framework 2 - BjyAuthorize Entity was not found. in /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php on line 177

Tags: doctrine, zend-framework2, bjyauthorize, proxyfactory

I started a project with Zend Framework 2 and I set up the modules ZfcUser and BjyAuthorize.
The ZfcUser part works correctly but when I active BjyAuthorize an error occurs

> Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException: Entity was not found. in /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php on line 177
>   Call Stack

here is my config file :
- comper.json

```
{
"name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
"description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "zf2"
],
"homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master",
    "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.8.0",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "v2.3.9",
    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "dev-master",
    "zf-commons/zfc-admin": "dev-master",
    "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "1.4.0"
}
}
```

application.config.php

```
return array(
'modules' => array(
    'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'ZfcAdmin',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'ZfcBase',
    'ZfcUser',
    'ZfcUserDoctrineORM',
    'BjyAuthorize',
    'Application',
    'Fountain',
    'Rest',
),
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor',
    ),
    'config_glob_paths' => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
    ),
),
);
```

bjyauthorize.global.php

```
  return array(
 'bjyauthorize' => array(
    'default_role' => 'guest',
    'identity_provider' => 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ZfcUserZendDb',
    'role_providers' => array(
        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\Config' => array(
            'guest' => array(),
            'user'  => array('children' => array(
                'admin' => array(),
            )),
        ),
        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ZendDb' => array(
            'table'                 => 'role',
            'identifier_field_name' => 'id',
            'role_id_field'         => 'roleId',
            'parent_role_field'     => 'parent_id',
        ),
        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ObjectRepositoryProvider' => array(
            'role_entity_class' => 'Fountain\Entity\Role',
            'object_manager'    => 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default',
        ),
    ),

    'resource_providers' => array(
        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Resource\Config' => array(
            'pants' => array(),
        ),
    ),
    'rule_providers' => array(
        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Rule\Config' => array(
            'allow' => array(
                array(array('guest', 'user'), 'pants', 'wear')
            ),
            'deny' => array(
                // ...
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'guards' => array(
        'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' => array(
            array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index', 'roles' => array('guest','user')),
            array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'stuff', 'roles' => array('user')),
            array(
                'controller' => array('index', 'static', 'console'),
                'action' => array('list', 'manage'),
                'roles' => array('guest', 'admin')
            ),
            array(
                'controller' => array('search', 'administration'),
                'roles' => array('staffer', 'admin')
            ),
            array('controller' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => array()),
        ),
        'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route' => array(
            array('route' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => array('user')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/logout', 'roles' => array('user')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/login', 'roles' => array('guest')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/register', 'roles' => array('guest')),
            // Below is the default index action used by the ZendSkeletonApplication
            array('route' => 'home', 'roles' => array('guest', 'user')),
            array('route' => 'home', 'roles' => array('guest', 'user', 'admin')),

            array('route' => 'fountain', 'roles' => array('guest', 'user')),
            array('route' => 'fountain/add', 'roles' => array( 'admin')),
            array('route' => 'fountain/delete', 'roles' => array('admin')),
            array('route' => 'fountain/edit', 'roles' => array('admin')),
        ),
    ),
),
);
```

zfcuserdoctrineorm.global.php

```
return array(
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        // overriding zfc-user-doctrine-orm's config
        'zfcuser_entity' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'paths' => array( __DIR__ .'/../../module/Fountain/src/Fountain/Entity'),
        ),

        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                'Fountain\Entity' => 'zfcuser_entity',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),

'zfcuser' => array(
    // telling ZfcUser to use our own class
    'user_entity_class'       => 'Fountain\Entity\User',
    'enable_default_entities' => false,
),
);
```

Anyone have an idea of the origin of this problem?

Comment: The means a proxy (entity) could not be loaded (it's identifier cannot be found in the database table that you setup for it in your mapping) [a well placed `var_dump($proxy)` in  the ProxyFactory](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php#L175) will tell you *which* entity class it is and also, when output, the id of the row it is trying to use to load -It might help to update your question with the mapping of the entity as well.